# jQuery Toggle div and class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**CSS:**

```
.project_toggle_on {
    padding-right:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background: url(../images/minus.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.project_toggle_off {
    padding-right:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background: url(../images/plus.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<span class="project_toggle_off" onclick="toggle_timesheet('10');"></span>
<div style="display: none;" id="task_10" class="task_project_id"></div>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
function toggle_timesheet(task_id) {
    //$(this).toggleClass('project_toggle_off');
    $("#" + task_id).slideToggle(100);
}
```

The above code works to show/hide the `div`, but how can I add/remove class to show `plus/minus` sign when it is toggled ?

Initially, plus sign will be shown and div will be hidde. When clicked on it, minus sign will be shown and div will be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the current element as a param to the click handler and then toggle the class

```
<span class="project_toggle_off" onclick="toggle_timesheet('10', this);"></span>
<div style="display: none;" id="task_10" class="task_project_id"></div>
```

then

```
function toggle_timesheet(task_id, el) {
    $(el).toggleClass('project_toggle_off project_toggle_on');
    $("#" + task_id).slideToggle(100);
}
```

---

I would recommend using jQuery event handlers instead of using inline handlers

```
<span class="project_toggle project_toggle_off" data-task="10"></span>
<div style="display: none;" id="task_10" class="task_project_id"></div>
```

then

```
$('.project_toggle').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('project_toggle_off project_toggle_on');
    $("#task_" + $this.data('task')).slideToggle(100);
})
```

Comment: Arun P Johny: Is it possible to add tooltip in span showing different message on toggle ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy are you using any tooltip plugin or the default tooltip

Comment: For now, default `title` as my tooltip.

Comment: Arun P Johny: Your code works like charm. Glad about your recommendation for using event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.toggleClass()` with clicked elements context, you can pass the object in onclick method:

**JS:**

```
function toggle_timesheet(task_id,obj) {
  $(obj).toggleClass('project_toggle_off');
  $("#" + task_id).slideToggle(100);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<span class="project_toggle_off" onclick="toggle_timesheet('10',this);"></span>
<div style="display: none;" id="task_10" class="task_project_id"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like jQuery also not works for show/hide div.
Your code should be as below:

HTML:

```
<span class="project_toggle_on project_toggle_off" onclick="toggle_timesheet('10', this);"></span>
<div style="display: none;" id="task_10" class="task_project_id"></div>
```

jQuery

```
function toggle_timesheet(task_id, toogleObj) {
 $("#task_" + task_id).slideToggle(100);
 $(toggleObj).toggleClass('project_toggle_off');
}
```